# App in docker container is not accessible on the listening port with net=host

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have an app listening on port 4000 and have a need to run it in a container with `--net=host` for simplified access to services on the host. According to docs and lots of similar questions about `--net=host`, I should be able to get to my app as easy as `telnet localhost 4000`, but that's not the case: the app in container is not accessible. If I run the container w/out `--net=host` and with `-p 4000:4000`, it works, but unfortunately I can't go with it.

- Docker Version: `17.03.1-ce-mac5 (16048)`
- OS: `OS X 10.12.4`
- docker run command: `docker run --rm -it --net=host -v /app/dir:/opt/app --name app-dev bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix:1.4.2 iex -S mix phx.server`

Comment: Post the Dockerfile and full run command you're using please :)

Comment: @johnharris85 Updated post with docker run command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that on Mac/Windows a thin VM is used as Docker needs a Linux kernel to operate. So using `--net=host` will not work as you expect, essentially this will use the host network of the VM. You should be able to verify this by accessing port 4000 of the docker VM.

For your use case I would recommend porting the other services to docker, if that is not an option running a local DNS resolver like [dnsmasq](https://www.google.de/search?q=dnsmasq+mac&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=VUQLWbnNLKz-6ATuiJ84) should do the trick. Just let some domain names resolve to your Mac host ip.

Comment: Just thought that I'm running a "native Docker for Mac client" - doesn't it mean container should use host's network rather than the VM one assuming there's no VM in "native" client? Or I misunderstand "native" meaning?

Comment: It's a bit misleading yeah, the Docker client may be native, but you still need a Docker daemon to run your containers and for that you always need a Linux kernel somewhere. Recent Docker for Mac/Windows versions also integrate with native host-virtualization (e.g. Apple Hypervisor framework and Microsoft Hyper-V).